# Nodejs, RabbitMQ and RestAPI

Tags: node.js, rest, express, rabbitmq, microservices

I have been breaking my head over this for over 2 weeks now and I don't seem to understand if what I'm doing is considered right or good practice. So I have been trying to implement a simple todolist of sorts with 2 services, the task service and the user service. I have created a few AMQP connections by reading through the documentation and was able to implement a request/reply pattern. What I don't get is, Am i doing this the right way? or is there a better way to do this? I'm pretty new to rabbitMQ and have plans of using this in my upcoming project with microservices. I understand the concept behind it but the implementation aspects of it seem bleak and I'm tired of going through very simple demo explanations.
Heres the application. Hope I get some help with this.
[RabbitMQ and Nodejs with RestAPI](https://github.com/shravan26/TaskManager)

I have posted it in rabbitmq groups but I have no luck yet. Any help will be nice.

Comment: You could _not_ use microservices and end up with something that's likely a lot better

Comment: I'm just using this to understand the working. The actual use is for something much bigger. But I thought I would learn how to use the basics here.

Comment: Almost nobody should be using microservices though. Best to stay clear until you are a much larger corporation.